# What is the best way to post form with multiple components using Vue js

Tags: forms, webpack, vue.js, vue-component

as I'm on my Vue spree (started recently but so far I'm really enjoying learning  this framework) couple of questions rised up. One of which is how to post form from multiple components. So before I continue forward I wanted to ask you  what are you thinking about this way of structuring and point me in right direction if I'm wrong.

Here it goes. 
I'm working on a SPA project using ASP.NET CORE 2.1 and Vue JS Template (with webpack)(https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter) and my project is structured in several containers, something like this:
In my app-root i registered several containers

```
<template>

  <div id="app" class="container">

    <app-first-container></app-first-container>
    <app-second-container></app-second-container>
    <!--<app-third-container></app-third-container>-->
    <app-calculate-container></app-calculate-container>
    <app-result-container></app-result-container>

  </div>   
</template>

<script>
  // imported templates
  import firstContainer from './first-container'
  import secondContainer from './second-container'
  import calculateContainer from './calculateButton-container'
  //import thirdContainer from './third-container'
  import resultContainer from './result-container'

  export default {
    components: {
      'app-first-container': firstContainer,
      'app-second-container': secondContainer,
     // 'app-third-container': thirdContainer,
      'app-calculate-container': calculateContainer,
      'app-result-container': resultContainer
    }
  } 
</script>
```

In my first container I'm having several dropdowns and two input fields with my script file where I'm fetching data from API and filling dropdowns and input fields with fetched data.

Something like this ( entered some dummy code for demonstration)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Crops table</h1>

    <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server. {{dataMessage}}</p>

    <div class="form-row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label  for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">1. Some text</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" v-model="pickedCropType" @change="getCropsByType()">
          <option v-for="(cropType, index) in cropTypes" :key="index" :value="cropType.id" :data-imagesrc="cropType.imgPath">{{ cropType.name }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">2. Some text</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
          <option v-for="(crop, index) in cropSelectList" :key="index" :value="crop.id">{{ crop.name }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        cropTypes: null,
        cropSelectList: null,
        crops: null,
        pickedCropType: null,

      }
    },

    methods: {
      loadPage: async function () {
        try {
          //Get crop types and create a new array with crop types with an added imgPath property
          var cropTypesFinal = [];
          let responseCropTypes = await this.$http.get(`http://localhost:8006/api/someData`);
          responseCropTypes.data.data.forEach(function (element) {

            cropTypesFinal.push(tmpType);
          });


        } catch (err) {
          window.alert(err)
          console.log(err)
        }
      },
      getCropsByType: async function () {
        //Get crops by crop type
        let responseCrops = await this.$http.get(`http://localhost:8006/api/crop/Type/${this.pickedCropType}`);
        var responseCropsData = responseCrops.data.data;
        this.cropSelectList = responseCropsData;
      }
    },

    async created() {
      this.loadPage()
    }
  }
</script>
```

And in my second container I have different dropdowns and different input fields with different scripts etc.

So, my questions are:

**1.)** I'm having required data form field in first container and in second container I'm having additional data and my submit button is separated in third container (app-result-container). So, is this proper and logical way of structuring containers if not can you point me in right direction?

**2.)** Is it smart to input script tag in every container where I'm processing/fetching/submitting some data for that particular container? Should I put scripts tag in separated file and keep structure clean, separating  html from js file.

Example:
import { something } from 'something'

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      someData: 'Hello'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    consoleLogData: function (event) {
      Console.log(this.someData)
    }
  }
}
```

**3.)** Can I send input values from one container to another (In my particular case from first and second container to app-calculate-container(third container))?

How to on submit return results container with calculated imported values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want components to communicate or share data with one another, you will need to either `emit` an event from one component up to the parent and pass it down via props, or use some kind of state management model, like Vuex, where each of your components can listen to the store.

Take a look at this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/8144oy7xy2

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <child-input @input="updateName" />
    <child-output :value="name" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildInput from "@/components/ChildInput.vue";
import ChildOutput from "@/components/ChildOutput.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ChildInput,
    ChildOutput
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateName(e) {
      this.name = e.target.value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**ChildInput.vue**

```
<template>
  <input type="text" @input="changeHandler">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildInput",
  methods: {
    changeHandler(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**ChildOutput.vue**

```
<template>
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildOutput",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**What's going on?**

The `ChildInput` component is a text field and on every change inside it, fires an event (emits using `this.$emit()` and passes the whole event *up*).

When this fires, `App` is listening to the change, which fires a method that updates the name data property.

Because `name` is a reactive data property and is being passed down as a prop to the `ChildOutput` component, the screen re-renders and is updated with the text written.

Neither `ChildInput` nor `ChildOutput` knows about one another. It's the parent that listens to the event passed to it, then passes the new prop down.

This way of working is fine and simple to understand, but I would strongly recommend looking at Vuex, as this method can get messy and complicated when you go beyond trivial tasks.

Comment: Thanks for elaborate answer. I ll try to figure it out using your explanation. I do have one question, is my way of "structuring application" proper way or should I use some different approach?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a true proper way...but I always use the Vue Cli to set up a new project and I find that it's a great starting point. Have you tried it? https://cli.vuejs.org/

Comment: Thank you for your pointers and directions :) In fact I did try it and I must say that I like it a lot :)

Comment: Great stuff, helped me very much.

Comment: What about multiple input. Let's take a example of a AddressInputs component (which has few pre-design inputs). How to send that data to parent component named CompanyRegForm? We can discuss it on chat.